# why stored proc always returning 0 in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored proc that will take two input parameters
1.Table name
2. Column name
and find the maximum from the column.
The stored proc is created successfully in DB.Here is the definition

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GETMAXIMUMID`(IN `tab_name` VARCHAR(40), IN `col_name` INT(10))
BEGIN
 SET @t1 =CONCAT('SELECT max(',col_name,') FROM ',tab_name );
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I am calling it as

```
CALL GETMAXIMUMID('tbl_segment','id');
```

but it is always returning 0 as result for every table.

Please let me know where I am wrong.I am trying stored proc for the first time and this is what I have learnt in few days.

Comment: `col_name` - integer? seriously?

Comment: I am getting `ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'id' for column 'col_name' at row 1`   (Mysql 8.0.22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE 
/* DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` */
PROCEDURE `GETMAXIMUMID`(IN `tab_name` VARCHAR(64), IN `col_name` VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
 SET @t1 =CONCAT('SELECT max(',col_name,') FROM ',tab_name );
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6094e04b96786ecae6a52cbb2046ad72)

Answer (score 3):

You declared `col_name` is an integer parameter, but you pass `'id'` as the value.

MySQL converts a string to an integer by reading any initial digit characters and ignoring the rest. If there are no digit characters, the value is converted to 0.

So you are preparing and executing this query:

```
SELECT MAX(0) FROM tbl_segment
```

Which naturally returns zero.